# SSL certificate on Google App Engine not working properly

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I configured SSL certificate on the google app engine. For configuration i followed the google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_ssl_to_your_custom_domain). The issue which i am facing is that when ever i access the website through this link https://www.dactyllab.com/ it shows that website is secured. But when i simply open [www.dactyllab.com](http://www.dactyllab.com/) the website did not show that it is secured. Kindly help me.

**Edit:**

Now it is working fine on mobile but whenever i open it on web it shows me this warning.
[image]

Comment: check also if your certificate isn't between those recently revoked by godaddy: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/01/11/godaddy_pulls_unvalidated_digital_certs/

Comment: @DanCornilescu I am facing this issue only when i open [www.dactyllab.com](https://www.dactyllab.com). If i open [dactyllab.com](https://dactyllab.com) it works fine in chrome but not in firefox. I also checked my website through [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/help/) and it says my certificate has not been revoked.

Comment: I'm getting a Godaddy page saying "Welcome to dactyllab.com Learn how you can get this domain", I believe you have a DNS configuration error, it shows, in addition to the 4 expected 216.239.X.21 addresses an unexpected one, apparently random: `dactyllab.com has address 184.168.221.44` or `dactyllab.com has address 50.63.202.51`.

Comment: BTW, my earlier revoked certificate comment was trigerred by the actual error code in the image you have in your post: `ERR_CERT_REVOKED`. I guess it *is possible* to be caused by a response coming from these non-GAE servers.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Now when i try to access my naked domain it is saying "The domain dactyllab.com is no longer parked by GoDaddy." But I already added all the provided A and AAA records from Google to Godaddy.

Comment: Yep, you need to figure out the DNS story.

Comment: Alright i will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application):

> - A naked domain, such as `example.com`, maps to `http://example.com`.

So it maps to the **non-secured** (i.e. `http`, not `https`) URL of the domain. This is because a custom domain can be equally well used for sites which don't use SSL.

If you want it to always get the secured URL just configure its handler with `secure: always` in the `app.yaml` file. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_element):

> **secure**
>
> Optional. Any URL handler can use the **secure** setting, including
>   script handlers and static file handlers. The **secure** element has
>   the following possible values:
>
> ...
>
> - **always**
>
>   Requests for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same path.
>     Query parameters are preserved for the redirect.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> handlers:
> - url: /youraccount/.*
>   script: accounts.app
>   login: required
>   secure: always
> ```

Update:

Your naked domain redirection works OK now. The page loads fine for me in both desktop FF and Chrome.

It does show an error on my old android phone: `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. I had a similar problem a while ago, my certificate was missing intermediate authorities, I just got a new certificate and verified it to be complete.

I just confirmed it for your site using [digicert](https://www.digicert.com):

> SSL Certificate is not trusted
>
> The certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against
>   Mozilla's root store). If you bought the certificate from a trusted
>   authority, you probably just need to install one or more Intermediate
>   certificates. Contact your certificate provider for assistance doing
>   this for your server platform.

Comment: I edited my question can you please tell me about this error now.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your GoDaddy control panel for the domain, and turn on "Domain Forwarding".  Forward to the `https:` address.  Then, whenever someone types in the `www` or `http:` address, it will forward to the `https:` address.

This does not always work, so you may want to make your own redirect script.  Or, in your app.yaml, add `secure: always`:

```
- url: /.*
  script: my.application
  secure: always
```

Comment: I tried you first method and now the website is not opening.

Comment: Kindly tell me now whats the problem?